# AWS QLDB - Terraform for creating table

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-qldb

Do anyone knows any CloudFormation to create table (not ledger) at QLDB via Terraform?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-qldb-ledger.html

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your interest in QLDB. Since table is not a AWS resource as Ledger does, you can't create table via CloudFormation.

Comment: but it should be available? Because dynamoDB has this option

Comment: @AndréLuísOliveira, DynamoDB is a single table itself